# Extract the Correct Column from the Result of lapply in R

Tags: r, gis, lapply, raster, shapefile

I have a bathymetry raster and a bounding gridded shapefile.

I cannot isolate the 'values' column of the list that lapply produces.

The intention is to use the raster mean values column as a new column in the shapefile

```
library("sf")
library("raster")

download.file("https://transfer.sh/T8BJjo/Raster.tif", destfile = "Raster.tif", method = "curl")

Raster_Data <- raster("Raster.tif")

download.file("https://transfer.sh/FgqHhS/HexGridShapefile.gpkg", destfile = "HexGridShapfile.tif", method = "curl")

GridShapefile <- st_read("HexGridShapfile.tif")

Raster_Values <- extract(Raster_Data, GridShapefile)

Mean_Raster_Values <- lapply(Raster_Values, FUN=mean)

#Extract Mean Values and set them to Column of Shapefile
GridShapefile$Raster_Values <- Mean_Raster_Values[[3]]  # INCORRECT IMPLEMENTATION
```

The last line should be assigning entire third column from Mean_Raster_Values list object but [[3]] only provides the third row

How to access the third column from Mean_Raster_Values ?

Comment: Your code is giving some errors especillay the `extract` step.  Can you show the package versions and the package used for `extract` (as extract is found in multiple packages)

Comment: code updated.   Extract taken from package raster 3.6-14

Comment: I tried your updated code, The last line where you mentioned it is failing is working fine for me.  Is there any errors

Comment: Your code says to extract the 3rd mean value from the list.  Instead if we want to use the whole list as a column, `unlist` and assign i.e. `GridShapefile$Raster_Values <- unlist(Mean_Raster_Values)` as the list elements are numeric and the length is one per list element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may need to `unlist` the `list` to a `vector` as each list element is numeric and is a single value (`mean` returns a single numeric output)

```
GridShapefile$Raster_Values <- unlist(Mean_Raster_Values)
```

-output

```
> head(GridShapefile)
Simple feature collection with 6 features and 1 field
Geometry type: POLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: 1.276447 ymin: 39.20347 xmax: 1.351447 ymax: 39.47771
Geodetic CRS:  WGS 84
                            geom Raster_Values
1 POLYGON ((1.301447 39.24677...     -691.8400
2 POLYGON ((1.301447 39.33337...     -967.5200
3 POLYGON ((1.301447 39.41997...    -1357.5200
4 POLYGON ((1.326447 39.20347...     -588.7440
5 POLYGON ((1.326447 39.29007...     -811.5081
6 POLYGON ((1.326447 39.37667...    -1156.5040
```

---

If we have use `sapply` instead of `lapply`, it would have returned a vector as by default `simplify = TRUE` in `sapply` and thus we could have directly created the column

```
GridShapefile$Raster_Values <- sapply(Raster_Values, FUN=mean)
```